# How can I create a Collapsible Tree View with checkboxes in pure javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create a tree view accordion structure using css and javascript only, no libraries.

In this tree view, all elements have to be checkboxes, so when they get checked they display the children and when they get unchecked they hide them.

Please anyone can help me.

Below is an example image of what i need to reproduce, but with checkboxes, doesn't have to look that way exactly.

[image: Sample Image]

Thanks.

Comment: why does it have to be all javascript, cant you have css? cause either way, you'll have to add some css in your javascript...

Comment: have you tried something?

Comment: @Erubiel  I can use css..I just cant use Jquery.

Comment: yess..I tried but tht's not working properly..shall I share? If you want @Erubiel

Comment: It would be good as a starting point, you could even just use CSS, this is redundant lol but, check the `:checked` selector https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/c/checked/

Comment: To open child and then their grandchild one by one I need to use JS

Comment: @Lavy, you should show the code you have tried so we can better help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this out, is a very simple solution i just made, its missing the minus and plus icons those you can add em with css.

https://jsfiddle.net/erubielgm/93k1wqxg/

**CSS**

```
.child-check{
  margin-left: 15px;
  display: none;
}

.child-check.active{
  display: block;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent-check">
   <input type="checkbox"><label>Level 1</label>
   <div class="child-check">
     <input type="checkbox"><label>Level 1.1</label>
     <div class="child-check">
       <input type="checkbox"><label>Level 1.1</label>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="parent-check">
   <input type="checkbox"><label>Level 2</label>
     <div class="child-check">
       <input type="checkbox"><label>Level 2.1</label>
     </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var checks = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]");

for(var i = 0; i < checks.length; i++){
  checks[i].addEventListener( 'change', function() {
    if(this.checked) {
       showChildrenChecks(this);
    } else {
       hideChildrenChecks(this)
    }
  });
}

function showChildrenChecks(elm) {
   var pN = elm.parentNode;
   var childCheks = pN.children;

  for(var i = 0; i < childCheks.length; i++){
      if(hasClass(childCheks[i], 'child-check')){
          childCheks[i].classList.add("active");      
      }
  }

}

function hideChildrenChecks(elm) {
   var pN = elm.parentNode;
   var childCheks = pN.children;

  for(var i = 0; i < childCheks.length; i++){
      if(hasClass(childCheks[i], 'child-check')){
          childCheks[i].classList.remove("active");      
      }
  }

}

function hasClass(elem, className) {
    return new RegExp(' ' + className + ' ').test(' ' + elem.className + ' ');
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help :) your code expanding child elements vry well but not collapse when we click on them.I am trying to understand your code and working on collapsing them.

Comment: Maybe you copied the wrong code, i edited the answer 3 or 4 times, also the fiddle. Check the last edits, they should work, error was i still used .add('active') instead of remove("active"). i also updated it so it just opens one level at the time.

Comment: yess my fault...you have saved me..Thanks a ton, @Erubiel :) :)

Comment: Glad to be helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Check this link  [Refrence Link](https://www.cssscript.com/demo/collapsible-folder-tree-pure-javascript-jslists/)

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>JSList - Very simple nested list example</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>
   * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
   }
   html,body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    font-size: 18px;

   }
   /* ONLY required CSS */
   ul,ol{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
   }
   li{
    list-style: none;
   }
   .headBnr{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: #ccc;
   }
   .simpleListInfo{
    position: absolute;
    right: 5%;
    top: 12%;
    width: 65%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
   }
   .simpleListContainer{
    position: absolute;
    left: 3%;
    top: 15%;
    width: 15%;
    min-width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(165, 165, 165);
    padding: 15px;
   }
   #title {
    font-size: 26px;
    font-weight: 900;
    padding-left: 3%;
   }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<header>

</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google_ad_client = "ca-pub-2783044520727903";
    google_ad_slot = "7946467596";
    google_ad_width = 300;
    google_ad_height = 250;
</script>
</div>
</header>
<main>
<div class="simpleListContainer">
<ul id="simple_list">
<li>
<i class="fa fa-folder-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<b>Folder One</b>
<ul>
<li id="aa1"><i class="fa fa-file-text-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Click Me</li>
<a href="https://www.google.com"><li><i class="fa fa-file-text-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Item Two</li></a>
<li><i class="fa fa-file-text-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Item Three</li>
<li><i class="fa fa-file-text-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Item Four</li>
<li><i class="fa fa-file-text-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Item Five</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li>
<i class="fa fa-folder-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<b><a href="#">Folder Two</a></b>
<ul>
<li><i class="fa fa-folder-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Item One
<ul>
<li><i class="fa fa-file-text-o" aria-hidden="true"></i><a href="#"> A</a></li>
<li><i class="fa fa-file-text-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> B</li>
<li><i class="fa fa-file-text-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> C</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><i class="fa fa-file-text-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Item Two</li>
<li><i class="fa fa-file-text-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Item Three</li>
<li>
<i class="fa fa-folder-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Item Four
<ul>
<li><i class="fa fa-file-text-o" aria-hidden="true"></i><a href="#"> A</a></li>
<li><i class="fa fa-file-text-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> B</li>
<li><i class="fa fa-folder-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> C
<ul>
<li><i class="fa fa-file-text-o" aria-hidden="true"></i><a href="#"> A</a></li>
<li><i class="fa fa-folder-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> B
<ul>
<li><i class="fa fa-file-text-o" aria-hidden="true"></i><a href="#"> A</a></li>
<li><i class="fa fa-file-text-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> B</li>
<li><i class="fa fa-folder-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> C
<ul>
<li><i class="fa fa-file-text-o" aria-hidden="true"></i><a href="#"> A</a></li>
<li><i class="fa fa-file-text-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> B</li>
<li><i class="fa fa-file-text-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> C</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><i class="fa fa-file-text-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> C</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><i class="fa fa-file-text-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Item Five</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li>
<i class="fa fa-folder-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<b>Folder Three</b>
<ul>
<li><i class="fa fa-file-text-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Item One</li>
<li><i class="fa fa-file-text-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Item Two</li>
<li><i class="fa fa-file-text-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Item Three</li>
<li><i class="fa fa-file-text-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Item Four</li>
<li><i class="fa fa-file-text-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Item Five</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li>
<i class="fa fa-folder-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<b>Folder Four</b>
<ul>
<li><i class="fa fa-file-text-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Item One</li>
<li><i class="fa fa-file-text-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Item Two</li>
<li><i class="fa fa-file-text-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Item Three</li>
<li><i class="fa fa-file-text-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Item Four</li>
<li><i class="fa fa-file-text-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Item Five</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li>
<i class="fa fa-folder-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<b>Folder Five</b>
<ul>
<li>Item One</li>
<li>Item Two</li>
<li>Item Three</li>
<li>Item Four</li>
<li>Item Five</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</main>
<footer>
</footer>
<script>
(function(){"use strict";function e(){var e={};return e.greet=function(){console.log("** Welcome to JSLists **")},e.checkNodes=function(){},e.collapseAll=function(e){var t,l=Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName("UL")),s=Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName("OL")),n=l.concat(s);for(t=1;t<n.length;t++)n[t].setAttribute("class","jsl-collapsed")},e.openAll=function(e){var t,l=Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName("UL")),s=Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName("OL")),n=l.concat(s);for(t=1;t<n.length;t++)n[t].setAttribute("class","jsl-open")},e.generateCss=function(){var e=document.createElement("style"),t=".jslist-li{margin-left: 22px;}";t+=".jslist-ul{margin-left: 22px;}",t+=".jslist-ol{margin-left: 22px;}",t+=".jsl-collapsed{display: none;}",t+=".jsl-collapsed-arrow{float: left; clear: both; margin-right: 11px; width: 11px; height: 11px; cursor: pointer; background: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAsAAAALCAYAAACprHcmAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAAKJJREFUeNqEkc0JxCAQhUfRg7EJweN2IikoJWxBkm4EexCvur4gi4kuO/Dw532O48i89y8ieje5Jk5zlKaz6RAArbW7MYYYYxNZa+Uxxj2EcGVyALsxCdF9B5gj4wgopW7rfiNf1fgzxFAbaa2/xrZt15hznuHRwKERWmZ+dGEJF7RnNFNKN7jPCx54tj6SEIKklJOwDx8cMh9oeNPfH/wIMABbu2PPHYUsbQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==') no-repeat;}",t+=".jsl-open{display: block;}",t+=".jsl-open-arrow{background: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAsAAAALBAMAAABbgmoVAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAACRQTFRFtLS0tLS0tLS0AAAAtLS019fX8/Pz9PT09fX19vb29/f3+Pj4NWr6kwAAAAN0Uk5TK7P9wooeBQAAAD9JREFUCNdjYFRxcVFkYBBdvXv3UgEGrVVAoMDgPXPmzNkOcKrZ2LgbSHV0dICo8vLyagcGrbS0tCwFmD6IKQDtKxlF/vrVqgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==') no-repeat;}",e.styleSheet?e.styleSheet.cssText=t:e.appendChild(document.createTextNode(t)),document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(e)},e.paddULLists=function(e){var t,l=document.getElementById(e).getElementsByTagName("UL");for(t=0;t<l.length;t++)l[t].classList.add("jslist-ul")},e.paddOLLists=function(e){var t,l=document.getElementById(e).getElementsByTagName("UL");for(t=0;t<l.length;t++)l[t].classList.add("jslist-ol")},e.padLists=function(e){var t,l=document.getElementById(e).getElementsByTagName("LI");for(t=0;t<l.length;t++)"jsl-collapsed-arrow"!=l[t].childNodes[0].className&&l[t].classList.add("jslist-li");this.paddULLists(e),this.paddOLLists(e)},e.generateList=function(e){this.generateCss(),document.getElementById(e).style.display="none;";var t,l,s,n,a=document.getElementById(e).getElementsByTagName("LI");for(t=0;t<a.length;t++)if(a[t].id.length>0){if(s=document.getElementById(a[t].id),n=document.getElementById(a[t].id).getElementsByTagName("UL"),n.length>0){for(l=0;l<n.length&&("UL"!=n[l].nodeName&&"OL"!=n[l].nodeName);l++);n[l].setAttribute("class","jsl-collapsed");var o=document.createElement("div");o.setAttribute("class","jsl-collapsed-arrow"),o.setAttribute("id",a[t].id+t+"_tgl"),s.insertBefore(o,s.childNodes[0]),document.getElementById(a[t].id+t+"_tgl").addEventListener("click",function(e){document.getElementById(e.target.id).classList.toggle("jsl-open-arrow"),document.getElementById(e.target.id).parentElement.lastElementChild.classList.toggle("jsl-open"),e.stopPropagation()},!0)}}else{if(a[t].setAttribute("id",e+"tmp"+t),s=document.getElementById(e+"tmp"+t),n=document.getElementById(a[t].id).getElementsByTagName("UL"),n.length>0){for(l=0;l<n.length&&("UL"!=n[l].nodeName&&"OL"!=n[l].nodeName);l++);n[l].setAttribute("class","jsl-collapsed");var o=document.createElement("div");o.setAttribute("class","jsl-collapsed-arrow"),o.setAttribute("id",a[t].id+t+"_tgl"),s.insertBefore(o,s.childNodes[0]),document.getElementById(a[t].id+t+"_tgl").addEventListener("click",function(e){document.getElementById(e.target.id).classList.toggle("jsl-open-arrow"),document.getElementById(e.target.id).parentElement.lastElementChild.classList.toggle("jsl-open"),e.stopPropagation()},!0)}a[t].removeAttribute("id")}setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById(e).style.display="block;"},99),this.padLists(e)},e.applyToList=function(e,t){switch(t.toUpperCase()){case"UL":this.generateList(e,"UL");break;case"OL":this.generateList(e,"OL");break;case"ALL":this.generateList(e)}},e}"undefined"==typeof JSLists?window.JSLists=e():console.log("JSLists already defined.")})();
</script>
<script>
   document.getElementById('aa1').addEventListener('click', function(e){
    alert('You clicked link: ' + e.target.id);
   },true);
   JSLists.applyToList('simple_list', 'ALL');
  </script>
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-46156385-1', 'cssscript.com');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks..I have already checked out this..but this is not what I want.

Comment: yes it will give you an idea if you follow the code

Comment: yes, I tried..and still working on it.

Comment: Now try this updated one

Comment: thanks a lot, @Nikhil Ghuse your code is working totally fine in my local but unfortunately it's not at all working on my  "visualforce page" where I have to use. It's only displaying HTML content.

Comment: I don't have any idea of  "visualforce" but the matter of fact if it support javascript below ecmascript > 6 then it show work as expected..

Answer (score 0):

you counld use pure js but it would take long, so why not use jquery instead

Comment: yes but the requirement is in only JS. Cant use jquery

Comment: why use computer then? perhaps better use abacus? :)

Comment: so this is homework then? should have been marked as such